# Issue with Spring mvc:annotation-driven

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value = {TABLE_URL}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public TableModel checkAvailability(@ModelAttribute TableQueryForm TableQueryForm, 
        TableContext table, BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
    // body
}
```

Here TableContext is an interface which have an implementation and its working fine.

Recently I needed to add a custom date formatter, so after adding it to enable it I added the line

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
```

as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-conversion)

after adding this now my request is failing with the below exception

```
Wrapped by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface com.table.domain.search.TableContext
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
```

The implementation of this class have no constructor defined, so by default the default one should get activated. I have no idea why this is happening. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: its an existing code and is working fine, without the new tag i mentioned.

Comment: Can you provide more info about TableContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injecting a custom java interface in spring handler is not possible without providing appropriate [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html). Please note the word "custom" as Spring can inject implementations of other interfaces like HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse,Reader,Writer etc. In these cases Spring injects the appropriate concrete implementation. For custom java class ( if it is only interface ) the reason this is not possible can be seen from the stacktrace of error you are getting. If there is no custom handler resolver for your interface, the resolving logic fallbacks on the  default ModelAttributeMethodProcessor which tries to find a constructor in all case for the mentioned interface class but since in java the interface cannot have constructor it fails ( note the line with FAILS HERE)

```
public class ModelAttributeMethodProcessor {

protected Object createAttribute(String attributeName, MethodParameter parameter,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory, NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {

        MethodParameter nestedParameter = parameter.nestedIfOptional();
        Class<?> clazz = nestedParameter.getNestedParameterType();

        Constructor<?> ctor = BeanUtils.findPrimaryConstructor(clazz);
        if (ctor == null) {
            Constructor<?>[] ctors = clazz.getConstructors();
            if (ctors.length == 1) {
                ctor = ctors[0];
            }
            else {
                try {
                    ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(); // FAILS HERE
                }
                catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("No primary or default constructor found for " + clazz, ex);
                }
            }
        }
......................................
......................................
```

I tried following test classes

```
public interface TestInterface {    
    public void test() ;
}

@Component
public class TestInterfaceImpl implements TestInterface {

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test called");      
    }

}
```

If my test controller is

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class TestController {   

        @GetMapping("test")
        public String withParam(TestInterface testInterface) {
            return "test";
        }
```

I get the same error as you

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface com.shailendra.TestInterface
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:132)
```

However if I use below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {   

    @GetMapping("test")
    public String withParam(TestInterfaceImpl test) {
        return "test";
    }
```

I get a proper response.

If the interface injection worked then it looks like earlier you had an appropriate HandlerMethodArgumentResolver configured, but somehow because of your change now it is not picked up ( maybe because configuration is excluded from spring scanning)

Comment: you are correct I was overriding the existing WebMvcConfigurationSupport
thank you

Answer (score 1):

An empty constructor is needed to create a new instance via reflection by your persistence framework. If you don't provide any additional constructors with arguments for the class, you don't need to provide an empty constructor because you get one per default. @u6f6o

You're probably providing additional constructors, so you should try implementing an empty constructor too.

Comment: I am using an interface, and the implementation class is not having additional constructors

Comment: Is the implementation class extending another class?

Comment: You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.

-Java documentation

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Java annotation Configuration or XML Configuration, if you are using Java annotation configuration, all you need to do is to remove your XML configuration files to make it work again.

If this doesn't solve your problems, please provide your configurations and your controller class to help clear the question up.

Answer (score 0):

I built a project like yours and it worked well, but I have no idea what properties are in your bean.
You can adjust by your real code

```
public interface TableContext {

    Long getDate();
}

public class TableContextImpl implements TableContext{

    private Long date;

    private String tableName;
    //getter setter ...
}
```

controller

```
public String testOne(@RequestParam("tableContext") TableContext tableContext)
```

configuration

```
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <ref bean="tableContextFormatter"/>
           </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    //this one is your custom formatter
    <bean id="tableContextFormatter" class="com.test.controller.TableContextFormatter"></bean>
```

formatter

```
public class TableContextFormatter implements Converter<String, TableContext> {


    @Override
    public TableContext convert(String s) {
        TableContext tc = null;
        if ( null != s ){
            tc = new TableContextImpl();
            //your formatting rules here
            ((TableContextImpl) tc).setDate(Long.parseLong(s));
        }
    return tc;
    }
```

}